# Write a layer in a specific table of a spatialite file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatialite

I'm manipulating several layers using python and qgis and I would like to save all those layers as separate tables in the same spatialite file.

At the moment I'm using :

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_file_path_str, 'utf-8',
  crs, 'SQLite', False, None, ['SPATIALITE=YES', ])
```

However, this only enables me to store one layer into one file. I can't figure out how to store several layers into the same file.

In a [qgis unit test](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/21ad4ed78bcac2916fc1f054347394b8d35c77c0/tests/src/python/test_qgsvectorfilewriter.py) file i found this :

```
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
```

But it seems to be outdated, i get errors such as AttributeError: type object 'QgsVectorFileWriter' has no attribute 'SaveVectorOptions'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one example of missing functionality in QGIS API v2 that [has been incorporated](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3597) (by Even Rouault) into [v3](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html).

---

Possible workarounds for QGIS v2:

### 1.

I use this solution in QGIS v2.14.8 for a company: run the Processing algorithm *Convert Format* from GDAL/OGR (you need to comment or remove [these two lines](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_14/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/ogr2ogr.py#L130-L131) in `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/ogr2ogr.py` for this solution to work):

```
res = processing.runalg( "gdalogr:convertformat",
        vLayer,
        3, #SQLite
        "-lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -update", # Creation options
        existingDBPath # Path to existing .sqlite file
      )
```

Because of some flaws in Processing, this solution works for PostgreSQL/PostGIS layers (enough for the company I work for), but it does not work for Shapefiles nor Memory layers. I wanted to fix this in [#3644](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3644) but unfortunately it was never merged.

### 2.

Use the [ogr2ogr port to Python](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py).

From PostGIS layer to SpatiaLite:

```
from ogr2ogr import *
main( [ "",
        "-f",
        "SQLite",
        "-lco",
        "GEOMETRY_NAME=geom",
        "-update",
        existingDBPath, # Path to existing .sqlite file
        "PG:{}".format( dataSourceURI.connectionInfo() ), # Connection string
        "{}.{}".format( dataSourceURI.schema(), dataSourceURI.table() ) # Tablename
      ]
   )
```

From a Shapefile QGIS layer to SpatiaLite:

```
from ogr2ogr import *
main( [ "",
        "-f",
        "SQLite",
        "-lco",
        "GEOMETRY_NAME=geom",
        "-update",
        existingDBPath, # Path to existing .sqlite file
        layer.source()
      ]
   )
```

### 3.

Save your layers in temporary files (e.g., Shapefiles) and directly run the ogr2ogr command:

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite -update myExistingDB.sqlite /docs/geodata/rivers.shp rivers
```

Comment: Thanks, so I guess what I found in the qgis unit test files was not outdated but rather for version 3.

Comment: Right, this is the same unit test but in v2: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_14/tests/src/python/test_qgsvectorfilewriter.py You can select which branch you want to navigate in a GitHub repository, by default is 'master' (which is v3).

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in shapefile format you may use ogr2ogr python module to add tables/layers to a sqlite db:

```
ogr2ogr.main(["","-update", "-overwrite", "-f", "SQLite", "{}".format(sqLiteDBPath), "{}".format(shpFilePath)])
```